# drawbacks of non positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I'm currently writing a report on the Element-free Galerkin method, which is a meshless method to solve PDES. In the method the stiffness matrix K(which is positive definite) has to be modified to impose the boundary conditions. The modification leads to a new matrix, M(defined below) which is not positive definite.

[image]

K and G are sparse matrices. Resulting system to solve is

[image]

In all the literature I've read this is reported to be a drawback of this particular method, but i don't understand why. We can still solve the final system so whats the difference ?

I'm using Matlab for the method and solving the system using

U = M\F

Thanks

Comment: Could $G$ have less than full rank? That would make $M$ singular. Or even if it has full rank, could $M$ be poorly-conditioned?

Comment: How would i tell if G had less than full rank, sorry i'm not overly familiar with that stuff. M is poorly conditioned ( It says so in Matlab !, and it says its singular to working precision). Is the reason for this because of the addition of the G matrix?.

Answer (score 1):

SPD matrices can be solved by the Conjugate Gradient (CG) algorithms and it's variations which are very efficient.

This is because SPD matrices have many very pleasent properties.

Also it is usually quite easy to show that a matrix is SPD, but if it isn't SPD you have to resort to more complicated tools to show that it is invertible, and you have to resort to more computationally expensive solving algorithms. But as long as you can use matlabs backslash operator you don't have to worry about it. It can even recognize non invertible matrices and use pseudo inverses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so the drawback of the matrix not being SPD is that i can't use these efficient methods then. My system is only a 2000x2000 array so solving the system isn't difficult, is there a point at which solving the Non-spd matrix would be much harder than the SPD one.

Comment: Well SPD is about the property you can get for efficiently solving linear systems, so any more general matrix is usually a lot more "difficult" to solve. If you are interested in this I would first take a look at the various different numerical methods for solving linear systems of equations.

Comment: Ah i see, yeah i think it would be helpful if i read up on that. Thanks for the help.